# is there a finite a finite subcollection $\mathcal K′$ of $\mathcal K $ such that $\mathcal \cap K′ ⊆ B $

Tags: logic, model-theory

Using the definition of a delta elementary class ($EC_\Delta$
) to be the set of structures which entail every formula in some set $\Gamma$
. We define an elementary class (EC) to be such a class generated by a finite $\Gamma$.

Suppose $\mathcal K$ is a class of $EC_\Delta$ classes—that is, the elements of $\mathcal{K}$ are $EC_\Delta$ classes of models— and suppose $\mathcal{B}$ is EC and that $\mathcal \bigcap \mathcal{K} \subseteq \mathcal{B}$. How to show that there is a finite subcollection $\mathcal{K}′$ of $\mathcal{K} $ (i.e., a finite collection of $EC_\Delta$ classes in $\mathcal K $) such that $\mathcal \bigcap \mathcal{K}′ \subseteq \mathcal{B}$.

Comment: Are you maybe in the same class as the person who asked this recent question? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2692089/7062 In any case, the answer to your question follows from the answer to that questions, plus the compactness theorem.

Comment: how would you approach using the compactness theorem to solve it? I don't see how it is relevant

Comment: In the notation of the other question, $\bigcup_i \Gamma_i \models \beta$. Can you show by compactness that for some finite subset $\Sigma$ of $\bigcup_i \Gamma_i$, $\Sigma\models \beta$?

Comment: how does that   Σ relate to K′

Comment: Ok, I'll spell it out for you. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Each class $K\in \mathcal{K}$ is $EC_\Delta$, so it is axiomatized by a theory $T_K$. And $\mathcal{B}$ is $EC$, so it is axiomatized by a sentence $\varphi$.

Then $\bigcup_{K\in \mathcal{K}} T_K$ axiomatizes $\bigcap \mathcal{K}$, and to say that $\bigcap \mathcal{K}\subseteq \mathcal{B}$ is to say that $\bigcup_{K\in \mathcal{K}} T_K\models \varphi$. By compactness, there are finitely many sentences $\psi_1,\dots,\psi_n\in \bigcup_{K\in \mathcal{K}} T_K$ such that $\{\psi_1,\dots,\psi_n\}\models \varphi$.

For all $1\leq i\leq n$, $\psi_i$ is in $T_{K_i}$ for some $K_i\in \mathcal{K}$. Let $\mathcal{K}' = \{K_1,\dots,K_n\}$. Then $\bigcap\mathcal{K}'\subseteq \mathcal{B}$.

Why? $M\in \bigcap\mathcal{K}'$ $\implies$ $\forall i, M\in K_i$ $\implies$ 
$\forall i, M\models T_{K_i}$ $\implies$ $\forall i, M\models \psi_i$ $\implies$ $M\models \varphi$ $\implies$ $M\in \mathcal{B}$.